# arm_navigation - cylindrical links don't avoid collision

Tags: urdf, arm-navigation

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi!

I'm following the [arm_navigation tutorials](http://www.ros.org/wiki/arm_navigation/Tutorials) and I went through the planning description configuration wizard successfully. However, when trying 'Planning Components Visualizer', I couldn't get my custom robot to avoid a pole, it would always go through it as if it wasn't there.

All links of my robot were defined as cylinders in the urdf file, but when I converted them to boxes, the robot started avoiding the pole successfully.

Is this supposed to be like this, or is it a bug (or my problem maybe)?

Thanks in advance!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/46108/arm_navigation---cylindrical-links-don%27t-avoid-collision/) by [Pedro](https://answers.ros.org/users/3142/pedro/) on ROS Answers with karma: 102 on 2012-10-17

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2012-10-17**:
Maybe you only added visual, but not collision? According to your description it doesn't seem so and it might be a bug that should be filed.

**Comment by [Pedro](https://answers.ros.org/users/3142/pedro/) on 2012-10-17**:
I added both. Visual can be a cylinder, as long as collision is a box.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I remember running into this problem as well. ODE, which is used by arm navigation for collision checking, does not support native cylinder-cylinder collision checks. This is known and should result in an error. I think there may even be a bug when checking collisions between other shapes and cylinders.

I don't think it will be fixed though, but the planned replacement MoveIT will use [FCL](http://gamma.cs.unc.edu/FCL/) for collision checks. It should work better there.

---

Originally posted by [AHornung](https://answers.ros.org/users/141/ahornung/) with karma: 5904 on 2012-10-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [David Lu](https://answers.ros.org/users/19/david-lu/) on 2012-10-17**:
I confirm this is a bug though I can't find the ticket at the moment. Recommended hack is to make a mesh of a cylinder.